# Django internationalization for beginners

Tags: django, internationalization

How to turn it on?

According to this http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/internationalization/

I put into my template /var/www/project/template/index.html

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
<html><body><h1>{% trans "It works!" $}</h1>
get_current_language = {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}<br>
get_available_languages = {{ LANGUAGES}}<br></body></html>
```

and in folder /var/www/project/template/ I create locale subfolder than I run

django-admin makemessages -l pl_pl

processing language pl_pl

and there's no files in locale/pl_pl/LC_MESSAGES/ (which are automagicaly created)

What should I do more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAMNED. I haven't noticed this:

```
<html><body><h1>{% trans "It works!" $}</h1>
```

___________________________________________________________________  **^**

Now it works.. I mean - it creates django.po and django.mo. But I still see It works - not translated strings. I even creates locales/en and locales/en_us with some different strings - still I see It works.

**SOLVED**
I have to put /var/www/project/templates/app/locale into settings.py to variable LOCALE_PATHS

Not intuitive.

Comment: If you put the locale folder in the same directory as settings.py, you don't need to specify the location.

Comment: but django-admin makemessages -l pl_pl wouldn't look into /var/www/project/templates, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your index file be in project/templates/  (with an s) ?
Otherwise, have you declared 'project' in your INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: typo. There is templates not template. Yes, it's also declared in settings.py